# How should i build UPD/TCP packets?

Tags: networking, tcp, udp, datagram

How do we build UDP/TCP packets lets say for games? I created just simple ping pong UDP and created 3 types of packet and first int(I used byteArrayStream to make it simple) of packet indicate how extract data. So it was INIT(int) /Player position(int,int,int)/Ball (int,int,int).
Is there any standard how data should be send via UDP/TCP or my technique is ok?
I know that i waste some data cuz i could use just one byte for init .

Comment: Sending binary data is usually not recommended, due to [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) issues as well as different sizes of "standard" types. If you still want to use raw binary data in your application protocol, then consider the endianness issues and use fixed-size data types.

Comment: What do you mean by "Sending binary data is usually not recommended" should i just send whole object?

Comment: That can be even worse as it's still binary data, and may contain information that are not able to pass from one process to another (depending on language and/or framework used). Instead consider using [*serialization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) and text-based messages.

Comment: ok thanks but every type of message should have id lets say uint16 ? and then rest of data